# Changing `rubyLocalVariableOrMethod` color in VIM

Tags: ruby, vim, syntax, colors, highlight

I was wondering whether it's possible to change the `rubyLocalVariableOrMethod` color in a `mytheme.vim` color scheme file.

I am currently extending the `ir_black` theme which I really like, and want to overwrite just a few a colors for certain keywords.

This is my current color scheme that extends from `ir_black`.

```
runtime colors/ir_black.vim

let g:colors_name = "mytheme"

hi rubyDefine ctermfg=darkblue
hi rubyFunction ctermfg=lightblue
hi rubyConstant ctermfg=lightblue
hi rubyString ctermfg=green
hi rubyInteger ctermfg=red
hi rubyFloat ctermfg=red
hi rubyLocalVariableOrMethod ctermfg=white
```

Everything works as expected except for `hi rubyLocalVariableOrMethod ctermfg=white`. The color remains something that looks like `gray`. I thought perhaps `ir_black` was setting a certain value that my `rubyLocalVariableOrMethod` could not overwrite, but I failed to find anything.

Perhaps someone more experienced in VIM could help me out with this.

This is the link to the `ir_black` I'm using:
https://github.com/wgibbs/vim-irblack/blob/master/colors/ir_black.vim

This is the `ruby` syntax file I am using:
https://github.com/vim-ruby/vim-ruby/blob/master/syntax/ruby.vim

Any help figuring out why I'm failing to overwrite the `gray`-looking color would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out my Terminal (`iTerm2`)'s `Foreground` property wasn't set to "full white". Didn't expect that to have any influence, but good to know in case anyone else runs in to this gotcha.

Answer (score 2):

Mine was actually "display transparent" in the syntax highlighting plugin.

```
~/.vim/bundle/vim-ruby/syntax/ruby.vim
92:syn match rubyLocalVariableOrMethod "\<[_[:lower:]][_[:alnum:]]*[?!=]\=" contains=NONE display transparent
```

I removed it and magic!